# Why i am not able to fetch table data in AJAX ? Everytime i fetch req_id from table it's gives me undefined value in Console.log

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to take req_id but everytime i fetch req_id from table it's gives me undefined in Console.log().Please see in table data req_id and yes the databse connection is okay i can see the value.I tried this both GET and POST method but still i get the same error.All i want is fetch req_id and show it in console.log as defined value

Thank You

```
<!-- main  -->
<section class="pad-70">
    <div class="container">
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <?php
        $userQuery = $connection->Show($conobj, "requested_car");
        if ($userQuery->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<table><tr><th>Req ID</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $userQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr ><td id=req_id>";
                echo (htmlentities($row['req_id']));
                echo ("</td><td>");
                echo ('<button onclick="confirmcar()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Confirm</button> <button onclick="MyAjaxFunc()" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button>');
                echo ("</td></tr>\n");
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $connection->CloseCon($conobj);
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- main  -->

<script>
function confirmcar() {

    var req_id = document.getElementById("req_id").value;
    console.log(req_id);


}
</script>
```

Comment: So you have a `<td id="req_id">` and you want to read its text contents in Javascript and print it as `console.log` ? Is that it ?

Comment: A `td` doesn't have `value`. Did you mean to get its `textContent`?

Comment: Aside from that, generating multiple elements with the same id is not valid markup (you're creating rows in a loop). Ids should be unique.

Comment: yes @julien.giband

Comment: so i am not able to do it with id as it's in a loop.could you please tell me how could i fetch the individual value like a req_id from table with button click? @El_Vanja

Comment: The simplest possible solution would be to make your `confirmcar()` function take a parameter and then pass the id to it inside the handler.

Comment: @sayem so, can you please clean up your code to let just the necessary html and javacript? This way you and us will be able to see where the problem is more easily. I think you can completely remove php, mysql and ajax from the equation. And who knows? You might even solve this by yourself

Comment: @julien.giband hey i think it's now more clear than previous one.All i want is take the value from table whenever i  click confirm value

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry .could you please specify it more clearly?how could i use id in a while loop?

Comment: When you generate the handlers, you put the id in there, e.g. `onclick="confirmcar(3)"`. Using PHP of course, this is just to demonstrate.

Comment: @El_Vanja no. it's still give me undefined value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, going from your last edit, I removed the PHP and tried to simulate the HTML that would be generated with several rows.

Now several points remained:

1. You have missing quotes around your attribute value `req_id`, as in `id="req_id"`. *(Not a real issue as @Quentin pointed out on another answer, but let's keep things tidy for the sake of our eyes)*
2. You're setting event handlers using `on...` html attributes, which is bad practice. Doing it with js `addEventListener` will help a lot solving your problem as you'll see below.
3. One of your problems is that you don't set a different `id` at each row for your `<td>`. If your ids are repeated, it probably means you should use a class instead. And setting different ids could have eased the process of selecting the right one on click. But it's not fatal so we'll go from here.

The code snippet below illustrates how you should proceed to get the value which is the inner text of the `<td>` with id "req_id" on the table row where the "Confirm" button was clicked:

- Add an event listener for each of these buttons, and when a button's clicked:
- climb up the DOM until you hit its parent `<tr>`
- within this row, find the `<td id="req_id">` by its id
- read its `innerText` property

```js
//When the DOM is fully loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _e => {
  //Find all buttons with class btn-success
  const buts = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-success');
  //Add a click handler to each one
  buts.forEach(button => {
    //When the button's clicked
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      //Find parent <tr>
      const tr = button.closest('tr');
      //Find child with id req_id and get its text
      const val = tr.querySelector('#req_id').innerText;
      console.log(val);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="pad-70">
    <div class="container">
        <p id="demo"></p>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Req ID</th><th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="req_id">My Value 1</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Confirm</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="req_id">My Value 2</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Confirm</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="100">...</td></tr>
          </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm using event `window.DOMContentLoaded` in order for my script to fire only after the DOM has been fully parsed from HTML. Else the buttons would not exist yet when trying to assign event handlers to them.

Comment: @sayem Who would have thought? ;-)

Comment: haha :) Although my problem is solved but i am newbie in Javascript so could you please tell me what should i learn or which topic i could find more knowledge about this.Is it advanced Javascript or JQuery? Thanks again :)

Comment: This is Javascript. Modern, but basic, no jQuery. The best resource for learning correctly is MDN. Their tutorials https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials . You should also find tutorials for good php coding. Search by yourself